# Facebook Invalid key hash Error

Tags: android, facebook, android-facebook

While running from code it runs fine. But after creating apk it gives invalid key hash.

That's why I added that key hash but still getting the same error. The keyhash with the error do not even match my key hash and I have also added my own key hash also.

Comment: when you do release version APK, I need to re-build of the keyhash, but do not know why they are different and this key to sign the application in fb

Comment: @PeDuCKA did not get your comment.

Comment: when you build release version APK, you need to re-build of the keyhash and this key to sign the application in fb

Answer (score 0):

By this function you can get your application key hash and update your key hash in facebook application and if getting same error than please check your application package name and application id in facebook developer console.

```
 public void generateHashkey() {
        try {
            PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
                    "com.integration",
                    PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
            for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
                MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
                md.update(signature.toByteArray());

                Log.i("Info", info.packageName + "\n" + Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(),
                        Base64.NO_WRAP));
            }
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Tried It it gives me same as in terminal by "keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64".   Which I have already added. I also added the one which is giving the error but still I am getting the same error

Comment: try again by using this function and if you want your application is used by all than check status and review option of developer console and enable the switch which is for all users can use your application

Comment: You getting your answer or not??

Comment: "2tICxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxzx4A=" This is what I got after just running the code which mine got from terminal. And "63y9**************DK2jU=" is I get when I create an apk and then run it in my device which is I donot know whose it is. I have added both and still getting the error of invalid key hash for second one.

Comment: I have also checked the status and review the switch is on.

Answer (score -1):

If you get Error like **"Invalid key hash and there is no any of key hases found in application of facebook page."** 
than please check your App Id and if it is different in your stored facebook application id in string.xml than you must to update your facebook id in string .xml from your facebook developer of application id.

Comment: Checked the app id it is correct. I donot know from where the key hash is getting added. Is there anything related to api version as I registered my app on api 2.2 and currently I am using sdk version 4.8.1

Comment: And the key hash is not of anybody in my team

Comment: You can get your key hash by oncreate function by following function.